# Use Aeron as a client to connect to non Aeron sever/API

Tags: aeron

guys

Has anyone use Aeron as a client to connect to a **non-Aeron** API/server? such as an external exchange service API which we usually write a client using socket programming to consume it, but I am just wondering if Aeron will be a good fit in this use case?

If yes, my second question will be what kind of performance impact we need to consider, because if consuming a external non-Aeron API, that means there is no Aeron media driver sitting on the server side to coordinate on the message...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aeron has its own transport protocol just like other messaging systems. Most exchanges have their own order entry and market data protocols that are based on TCP or raw UDP, they are not compatible with Aeron. Common protocols for interacting with exchanges include FIX which is nowhere near as efficient as Aeron.